# Gift certificate email not being sent in Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: email, opencart2.3

I am testing the Gift Certificates in Opencart 2.3.0.2. When successfully purchased, emails are sent to the admin and the buyer automatically but the Gift Certificate email with the voucher code is not sent to the recipient. 
Has anyone encountered the same issue?